# Qt qUncompress giving "could not allocate enough memory to uncompress data"

Tags: qt, memory-management, zlib

I have the following code which is failing when called with the error:

```
qUncompress: could not allocate enough memory to uncompress data
```

Code:

```
QString decStage3 ( QByteArray s )
{
    printf ( "3a: length in %d\n", s.length());
    QByteArray bData = QByteArray::fromHex(s );
    printf ( "3b: length ba %d\n", bData.length());
    printf ( "3c: ba [%s]\n", qPrintable(bData.toHex()));
    printf ( "3d: mem [%d]\n", bData.capacity() );

    QByteArray dS = qUncompress( bData );
   // QByteArray::fromHex(s.toLatin1());
    return (dS.data());
}
```

Example input is "789C0B492D2E5170492C490400101E033B" ( == "Test Data" ).

UPDATE: Following Chernobyl's suggestion, I decided to add the a direct test as follows:

```
void tst ( QByteArray b0 )
{
    QByteArray b1 = qCompress (b0);
    printf ( "[%s] %d = [%s] %d\n", qPrintable(b0), b0.length(), qPrintable(b1.toHex()), b1.length());
    QByteArray b2 = qUncompress (b1);
    printf ( "uncomp = [%s]\n", qPrintable(b2));
}
```

Then tested:

```
tst ("Hello");
tst ("Hello World");
tst ("Hello World Nice To See You");
```

This gave the following:

```
[Hello] 5 = [00000005789cf348cdc9c90700058c01f5] 17
uncomp = [Hello]
[Hello World] 11 = [0000000b789cf348cdc9c95708cf2fca490100180b041d] 23
uncomp = [Hello World]
[Hello World Nice To See You] 27 = [0000001b789cf348cdc9c95708cf2fca4951f0cb4c4e5508c957084e4d5588cc2f050082f70939] 39
uncomp = [Hello World Nice To See You]
```

Notice the first 8 bytes now appear to hold the length (hex) of the original string. I haven't come across this behaviour before. I can amend the source program to include this (from another system, in Java), but is there a way to avoid having to do this?

Comment: Do you call this function like decStage3(qCompress(arr))? (do you compress your data before call the function?) If you don't compress data, try to do this. Maybe after this you get qUncompress: Z_DATA_ERROR: Input data is corrupted  error???

Comment: The data is fine as it comes from another program which compresses. If I leave out a byte I get the invalid data error, so I believe the data is correct.

Comment: @TenG I've had a similar problem, the solution is to use tinfl or zlib directly on the DEFLATEd stream. Also could be a problem with the header, that is prepended.

Comment: @user1095106 - thanks, that should give me a way out. Is there an example of doing the above directly in zlib? I got #includes for <QtZlib/zlib.h> and "JlCompress.h".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a clearly documented aspect of `qUncompress`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed (or rather got it working) by preprending a dummy length before the zip data  (starting 789c):

```
QString decStage3 ( QByteArray s )
{
    printf ( "3a: length in %d\n", s.length());
    QByteArray bData = QByteArray::fromHex("00004000") + QByteArray::fromHex(s );
    printf ( "3b: length ba %d\n", bData.length());
    printf ( "3c: ba [%s]\n", qPrintable(bData.toHex()));
    printf ( "3d: mem [%d]\n", bData.capacity() );

    QByteArray dS = qUncompress( bData );
   // QByteArray::fromHex(s.toLatin1());
    return (dS.data());
}
```

It's the line where I declare bData, prepending it with "00004000". This evaluates to 16K. It turns out the although on compress this denotes the length of the uncompressed data, on uncompess it doesn't actually need to be the accurate length. So, assuming this is more to do with the memory grab used internally to do the uncompress, I opted for 16K as that will be more than enough for the data we expect.

Comment: This is documented: "Note: If you want to use this function to uncompress external data that was compressed using zlib, you first need to prepend a four byte header to the byte array containing the data. The header must contain the expected length (in bytes) of the uncompressed data, expressed as an unsigned, big-endian, 32-bit integer."